# Grouping similar Node links in attribute table of QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, attribute-table, vertices

I have a situation like this:

I have network with nodes (vertices) and points. I extracted the nodes using [Extract Vertices](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisextractvertices) in QGIS. After that I connected the vertices with points with perpedicular lines using j[oin-by-lines-hub-lines](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#join-by-lines-hub-lines) in QGIS. The problem here is:

- The attribute table is producing separate IDs for each link. Ideally, there should be a single ID of vertice for the same connected links.
- For instance, a single vertice (2628) in the below image is connecting five points, however, the attribute table is showing separate IDs for the same vertice. Ideally, there should single vertice ID with links column.
  Is there a way to group the links which are connected to the same vertice?

[image]
[image]